# When do we have linearly dependent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a $3 \times 3$ real invertible matrix $A$. If $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, so one of them has multiplicity $2$. Is it possible to have only two linearly independent eigenvectors? i.e., is it possible that the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Could you explain what the idea behind that is? How do we construct this kind of matrix?

Comment: I took a 2x2 matrix with only one eigenvalue that is not the identity, so it has only one eigenspace of dimension 1. I completed in an orthogonal basis so that it is an invertible matrix

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
For the eigenvalue 1,which has algebraic multiplicity 2, the dimension of the eigenspace is 1. Any eigenvector for eigenvalue 1 is a multiple of $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Could you explain what the idea behind that is? How do we construct this kind of matrix?